# Why am I getting an error on trying to assign arrays to each element of a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to create a list which should contain numeric values which I am trying to extract from a dataframe. The following is my code:

```
list_values = []
j = 0
for i in country_list:        
    list_values[j] = df6['positioning'][i].to_numpy()
    j = j + 1

print(list_values)
```

When I am trying to just print the values directly without storing them in the list I can do that, but somehow I am not able to store them in the list or a 2d numpy array. What is going wrong?

The following is the error:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @viggnah because i need to perform statistical hypothesis test on these values using anova so I thought of storing them in a list and then perform the test

Comment: use `list_values.append(df6['positioning'][i].to_numpy())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning, `list_values` is an empty list and `j` is 0.

So if you use `list_values[j]`, 0 is an invalid index for an empty list. Therefore you get this error.

You cannot ever grow a list by using index assignment. Index assignment can only replace list items that already exist. In order to grow a list, you can for example use the `append` method to add an item to the end of the list.